# MongoHQ create database with API doesn't add default user

Tags: mongohq

Pretty much what it says on the tin...  I'm using MongoHQ's REST API to create a database, but for some reason the default user account that gets created when adding a database manually via the web page does not get created when the API is used.  Am I missing some API documentation that indicates this is the expected behavior?  Is it a bug?  In any case, how can I programmatically add user accounts to a database?  Or is it possible?

For reference, MongoHQ's documentation is here: http://support.mongohq.com/mongohq-api/databases.html

Answer (score 0):

MongoHQ support has informed me that this is a bug in their API and there is no workaround.  A fix is in the works, but there is no timetable for its release.

Answer (score 0):

After Googling around, I found [this](https://github.com/abishekrsrikaanth/mongohq-api-laravel4/blob/master/src/Abishekrsrikaanth/MongohqApi/MongoHQ/Users.php) PHP MongoHQ API library. They had a create user function in there. I took a look, broke it apart, tested it and it works! It's undocumented, but it does allow you to add users to a database.

POST to:

```
https://api.mongohq.com/databases/*YOUR-DATABASE*/collections/system.users/documents?_apikey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

With a JSON payload:

```
{"document":{"user":"danmandle", "pwd":"test", "readonly":false}}
```

Comment: Interesting! I'm not in a position to try this anymore, but if someone else comments and says it works for them I'll accept this answer. Thanks!